# How can I assign character from file to a char type variable? (C)

Tags: c

I am reading in a file, and I am trying to take the first character from that file, and assign to to a variable: `currentChar`

I am getting the following error message:

> Incompatible types when assigning to type `char` from type `FILE {aka struct _IO_FILE}`

```
char inputFile[50] = "hello.txt"; 
FILE * inFile = fopen(inputFile, "r");
char currentChar;
currentChar = inFile[0];
fclose(inFile);
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: What does your text book show you?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle yes I accidentally submitted by pressing enter, as i wanted to type on a new line but it submitted this post, oops! Not used to using SO as haven't used it in a while

Comment: Please read the text book. Please read the manual page for `fopen`. PS: Check the return value there

Comment: You could use [a good beginners book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/440558).

Answer (score 2):

`FILE` is a structure holding metadata (filled in by `fopen()`), which is used as parameter by other functions that affect reading from the file. You never access what is in a `FILE` structure directly.

One of the file access functions is [fgetc()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc), which takes a `FILE *` as parameter and returns an `int` -- either `EOF` (end-of-file) or the next character from the file so identified.

```
char inputFile[] = "hello.txt"; 
FILE * inFile = fopen(inputFile, "r");
// inFile == NULL means fopen() failed
if ( inFile != NULL )
{
    int currentChar;
    currentChar = fgetc( inFile );
    // check currentChar for EOF, then do something with it
    fclose(inFile);
}
else
{
    perror( "fopen() failed" );
}
```

Comment: Good cleanup! you might also hint that `char inputFile[50] = "hello.txt";` is inadequate: `char inputFile[] = "hello.txt";` or `const char *inputFile = "hello.txt";` are safer alternatives, and using `fopen("hello.txt", "r")` is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

DevSolar gave a useful answer with corrections for your mistakes, and following his advice will let you read the file contents correctly.

Yet reading a file one *character* at a time may be more subtle than it looks: `fgetc()` or plain `getc()` returns either `EOF` or a *byte* from the file, a value of type `unsigned char`, which is necessarily the same type as `char`, and which does not necessarily represents a *character*, especially if the file is encoded with a multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8. This byte value can be safely stored to a `char` variable, but how to interpret it is the programmer's responsibility, depending on the actual file type and encoding.